# Magento REST API OAuth for mobile app

Tags: ios, magento, rest, oauth, authorize

I'm developing an iOS app that uses the Magento REST API, I'm following the documentation provided by Magento for the OAuth authentication (http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/authentication/oauth_authentication.html)

I use the initiate endpoint to get the request token but then when I want to authorize this token I need to use the "authorize" endpoint and there I get redirected to a URL where I have to provide customer credentials to authorize the request token. This is not the behaviour that I was expecting since the user would be already logged in using the app's login (not implemented yet). Is there a way of making this "authorization" step transparent for the user? Like calling some service passing it the user's credentials provided in the login screen of my app?

If there is no way I'll use the Magento's SOAP API

Comment: I hope you find one. I spent many days trying to develop code to make this work then gave up in frustration.

Comment: I am stuck with this issue for a week, did you have any success?

Answer (score 2):

I did that too really really painful Magento use OAuth1.x, basically you've got three options:

1. Do it yourself
2. Use some oAuth consumer lib, you can find them on github
3. Use [MKNetworkKit](https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKNetworkKit) with this [add-on](https://github.com/rsieiro/RSOAuthEngine) 
   I used the 3rd because oaf MKNetworkKit, and anyway there was still a lot of work to do, if you want to hide some passages injecting js.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm already using a OAuth library but in the "authorization" step I get redirected to a Magento URL where the customer has to login, I want to make this step transparent for the user, like calling a service or something. Do you know if this is possible?

Comment: You should inject some javascript that fill the form and use the buttons on a CGRectZero WebView

Comment: @Andrea If i try to get customer list using REST API i am getting error -> screenshot -> https://snag.gy/3PSxvm.jpg -> URL -> 127.0.0.1/anusthana/api/rest/customers. and if i try to get products its working -> screenshot -> http://snag.gy/sePpyw.jpg -> url 127.0.0.1/anusthana/api/rest/products, can i help regard customer API error?

Comment: @Rathinam I don't know, this is a really old question and I've never used Magento since then

Comment: @Andrea Thank you for your response.